# Flashget download graph like Windows Forms graph control

Tags: .net, winforms, graph, controls, visualization

Do you know if there is such a Windows Forms control/component to visualize something like the following:

[image]

This screenshot, taken from the popular download manager FlashGet, visualizes the download status of a file where the squares represent parts of the file being downloaded. And the colors represent the status of that part, gray -> not downloaded, blue -> downloaded, green -> being downloaded.

Also, if there isn't such an existing Windows Forms control for this, can you suggest a way to develop a custom control like this? The control should perform well with large data and handle scrolling. I think I should get my hands dirty with custom drawing and GDI stuff. Any starting pointer would be greatly appreciated.